# Spring Boot 3 Native with lombok immutable (@Value)

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, native, lombok, graalvm

I've been trying to create a example project using spring boot 3, graalvm, lombok and jpa. Everything looks perfect when I execute the test using the main method. But I have a problem when I run the native binary.

First I create the binary:

```bash
mvn -Pnative native:build
```

Then I run the project:

```
./target/demo
```

The project start fine, but when I try to create a new record using curl:

```
curl --location --request POST 'localhost:8080' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "name": "test",
    "surname": "surname"
}'
```

I see this error in console:

```
2022-12-21T01:51:48.055+01:00  WARN 105751 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .c.j.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter : Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type [[simple type, class com.example.demo.dto.ExampleDto]]: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Builder class `com.example.demo.dto.ExampleDto$ExampleDtoBuilder` does not have build method (name: 'build')
2022-12-21T01:51:48.055+01:00  WARN 105751 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content-Type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' is not supported]
```

My DTO looks like this:

```java
@Value
@Builder
@Jacksonized
public class ExampleDto {
    Integer id;
    String name;
    String surname;

}
```

The controller:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
@AllArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class ExampleController {

    private final ExampleService exampleService;

    @GetMapping
    public ExampleDto findByName(@RequestParam String name) {
        return exampleService.getByName(name);
    }

    @PostMapping
    public void save(@RequestBody ExampleDto dto) {
        exampleService.save(dto);
    }
}
```

The problem is pretty clear, there is a problem with the "build" method that is created by lombok. If I inspect the generated source I can see the method in the right place. Apparently GraalVM (or jackson) does not see the method.

I also tried to add some traces in a GET method just to be sure that the controller has access to to `builder.build()` method and the method exist in runtime. (2nd clue that gives me the idea that there is a configuration problem.

I removed the `@Value`,`@Jacksonized` and `@Builder` and put just `@Data` and everything works fine.

Any idea? Should I add an extra configuration?

The example project is in github: https://github.com/elysrivero99/spring-boot-3-native-demo

Comment: hi perhaps might be of interest https://blog.jdriven.com/2019/04/immutable-classes-with-spring-boot-lombok-and-jackson/

Comment: Missing reflection config probably?

Comment: Try adding `@TypeHint(types = ExampleDto.ExampleDtoBuilder.class, methods = {@MethodHint(name = "build")})` to your `DemoApplication`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a while I found the answer. You have to add the hints as:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportRuntimeHints(DemoApplication.DemoApplicationRuntimeHints.class)
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    static class DemoApplicationRuntimeHints implements RuntimeHintsRegistrar {

        @SneakyThrows
        @Override
        public void registerHints(RuntimeHints hints, ClassLoader classLoader) {
            hints.reflection()
                    .registerConstructor(ExampleDto.ExampleDtoBuilder.class.getDeclaredConstructor(), ExecutableMode.INVOKE)
                    .registerMethod(
                            ExampleDto.ExampleDtoBuilder.class.getMethod("build"), ExecutableMode.INVOKE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you really have to declare all DTOs? It didn't worked for me.